# the syntax for calling JSON format in HTML

Tags: angularjs, json

I have this syntax for calling JSON format in HTML

```
<div class="profile-nav col-md-3">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="user-heading round">
          <a href="#">
            <img ng-src="{{&apos;img/fk/&apos;+ user_info.photoURL +&apos;.jpg&apos;}}" >
          </a>
          <p style="color: #ffffff;font-size: 21px;"><b>{{user_info.displayName}}'s Profile</p> //from user's table

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p style="color: #000;font-size: 21px;"><b>his ability is {{user_extras.sifat}}</p>
<p>Description: {{sifat.item0.nama}}</p> //calling for sifat's table
```

How do I replace `item0` in Description: `{{sifat.item0.nama}}` from the user's table?

Ive tried these methods but they didn't work

```
<p>Description: {{sifat.{{user_extras.sifat}}.nama}}</p>
or
<p>Description: {{sifat.[user_extras.sifat].nama}}</p>
<p>Description: {{sifat.+'user_extras.sifat'+.nama}}</p>
```

Comment: What are `sifat`, `user_extras`, ... ?

Comment: I don't know your data, but I think this would be it: `{{sifat[user_extras.sifat].nama}}`